# Deployment of App with EMGU dlls hangs with capturing the video stream from IP Cam

Tags: emgucv

I have an applications that have EMGU controls and DLLs, the purpose of the said app to play and capture the video from the IP Cam using the EMGU version 3.1.0.2282, when I run this application in a workstation the program will stop after a few seconds while the video streaming is running. The windows will prompt "Program has stopped working".

Any idea about this

Answer (score 0):

I solved again my own problem.

I had a problem in my code, when i call and set the capture variable i consequently call the command capture.start(), the capture will start automatically when you set the capture device, to solve my prob, i remove the command .start().